# Does Git use the same heuristic for core.autocrlf and .gitattributes text=auto?

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

By adding `* text=auto` to a .gitattributes file, Git uses its own heuristic to determine if a file is text, as opposed to binary, for the purposes of line feed normalization. [(source)](https://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)

Presumably Git also needs a heuristic to determine if it will perform line feed normalization when `core.autocrlf = true`.

Is the same heuristic used for both cases?

Or in other words, is `core.autocrlf=true` functionally equivalent to `* text=auto` in a .gitattributes file where `core.eol=native` on a Windows machine? (Except that .gitattributes is per-repo, and `core.autocrlf` is per user/system)

Comment: The short answer is "yes": the automatic detection is the same for both. As you note there are a bunch of caveats if you go too far in claiming that these are "the same", it's just the *detection* part that's really the same.

Comment: Thanks @torek! Your answer gave me the courage to poke at the code. It seems like the relevant file is `convert.c` in the root of the [Git source tree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/tree/). Am I correct in assuming that `gather_stats` is gathering the data for the heuristic decisions? It seems that `crlf_to_worktree` is our hero? :)

Comment: `convert.c` is the right file, but some parts of its workings have always eluded me. `crlf_to_worktree` is static and called only from `convert_to_working_tree_internal`, which is also static but is called from three more functions. So indeed `crlf_to_worktree` is making the decision here, but this is under additional control to avoid having to decide in some cases (not smudging, not normalizing, no filter drivers). That's where I tend to run out of steam analyzing these paths. :-)

Comment: Very much understood :)